# Regular expression for a non-zero hex value

Tags: regex, hex

I am looking for a regular expression to determine when any of the values in a 32-bit hex value is non-zero.

The data patterns look like `0x00000000` and I want to know when any of the digits is non-zero.  For example, if `0x00001000` or `0x10000000` or `0xB000000` would be capture by the regular expression, but not a `0x00000000` pattern.  Right now I perform a walking pattern match of

```
0x[^0]
0x0[^0]
0x00[^0]
...
0x0000000[^0]
```

This will work, but I much rather have one pattern if possible. Thanks.

Mark

Edit:  I didn't mention as the RegEx was not needed in a program, otherwise I would have used a different approach, but I was using the RegEx to search for values in a log file using UltraEdit.  I could have developed a program or some other means to search, but I was just being lazy, just being honest.  Ben S solution worked both in UltraEdit and Rad Software Regular Expression Designer.  rampion solution didn't work in either tool, not sure why.

Comment: just match all hex values, then test if it is equal to zero

Comment: Or in other words, use `0x00000000` as your regex, and branch if it doesn't match.

Comment: rampion solution didn't work cause he included start and end regex slashes(/) which the editors don't need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not test the hex value against zero? Simpler, faster, more readable.

If a regular expressiong is really necessary, `0x0*[1-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]*` should do it.

It looks for as many zeros as it can until it finds a non-zero hex value, then gathers the rest of the hex regardless of if it's a zero or not.

**Note**: this will match any length hex, not just 32 bits.

Comment: this wouldn't allow zeros in the middle .. like 0x101

Comment: Of course it would.  No one said that the matched string has to end with the pattern.  The point is that the last 0* is superfluous.

Comment: my point is that 0x101 will only return 0x10 ... Not very sure that this is what lordhog wants ;)

Comment: Edited to fix the middle zero issue.

Comment: It's now similar to rampion's answer, which, I believe, is correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
/0x0*[1-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]*/
```

`<atom>*` means match the atom 0 or more times, so this pattern matches the `0x` prefix, followed by 0 or more `0`s, followed by a non-zero hex, followed by some hex.

Comment: I think that last * shouldn't be there, you want to match at least one non-zero character, and you don't need to match any paste the first.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try something slighly different.  Testing for a non-zero hex is much harder than testing for a zero hex.  So test for zero and manually do the not.

```
bool IsNonZeroHex(string input) {
  return !Regex.IsMatch(input, "^0x(0*)$");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/0x0*[^0]/
```

Comment: this will match the first list of zeros followed by a single non-zero ... something like 0x11 will return 0x1 only

Comment: This would match a line like "0x0,"   I'm tempted to downvote.

Comment: OP didn't say he was matching against a line, he said he was matching against a hex number.  If it were written for content in an arbitrary text line it would be different, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should cover all cases (if it really has to be a regex):

```
^0x(?=0*[1-9a-fA-F]0*)[0-9a-fA-F]{8}$
```

Comment: Would this force 0-padding since it requires a length of 8 characters. What about 0xfd3? That's still a valid 32-bit hex value.

Comment: Um, yes, I was focusing on the *exact* match. But since your solution does all that with a simpler regex, it doesn't matter anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed size hex numbers can be looked up using negative lookahead as:

```
/(0x(?!0{8})[0-9a-fA-F]{8})/
```

A group is looked up beginning with `0x`

then negative look ahead `0{8}` (fails if found)

otherwise match `[0-9a-fA-F]{8}`

Works with PCRE, JavaScript, Python. Don't know which editors support negative lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

Surely a simple string compare and if it `DOES NOT EQUAL` "0x00000000" you've got your match.

Am I over simplifying it? The is only one `FALSE` case, right? When the string is "0x00000000"?

Don't use RegEx unless you have to.

Comment: he wants non-fixed length, like 0x0 or 0x0000

Answer (score 0):

```
/0x0{0,7}[^0]/
```

'`0x`', followed by zero to seven '`0`', followed by something that is not '`0`'